# Embedded Excel COM Object clipboard interefernce

Tags: excel, com, clipboard, ole

I'm writing programs in C\C++ embedding Excel and handling it's COM object.
This automation process works flawlessly to manipulate sheets and getting benefit of excel capabilities.

M problem is that while processing data i use copy/paste operations, so if the processing takes some time, it's possible that interference happens as the clipboard is common between running processes

i don't know if there's a way privatize the clipboard or any other idea to avoid such problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make a private clipboard and expect it to work with normal cut/copy/paste operations.  You can use delays to avoid clipboard clashes. i.e. after you force a copy operation, wait a few hundred ms before pasting.

Also, programmatic use of the clipboard is considered bad practice. The clipboard is provided for the convenience of the user, not the programmer.  See my favorite quote on the subject:

> “Programs should not transfer data into our out of the clipboard
>   without an explicit instruction from the user.”   — Charles Petzold,
>   Programming Windows 3.1, Microsoft Press, 1992

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

First, i'd like to confirm that the enduser is aware of having his clipboard manipulated by my program, but my issue here is to prevent clipboard interference that may happen between my application and the other activities/applications the end user is doing

- You denied that a private clipboard would help, but you didn't deny that a private clipboard may exist, is that possible to give some process a private clipboard ?
- May you explain the purpose of the delay you suggest, how may delaying the past operation to minimize/remove interference

Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it for PowerShell scripts:

- Create a Scheduled Task that call your script/program
- Set it to "Run whether user is logged on or not"

When you run the Scheduled Task, Windows launch the script/program in a background session that uses its own Clipboard, not interfering with the one of the active session you have.